# Openshift war successfully deployed but I still see the default welcome page

Tags: java, maven, openshift

I pushed my skeleton app with spring mvc to openshift git repo. I saw success logs but actually when I go to my app url I see only default welcome page with instructions.. What I could miss?

Here is my remote maven log:

```
remote: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------        
remote: [INFO] Building WordParty 1.0-SNAPSHOT        
remote: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------        
remote: [INFO]         
remote: [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ wordparty ---        
remote: [INFO]         
remote: [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ wordparty ---             
remote: [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.        
remote: [INFO] Copying 1 resource        
remote: [INFO]         
remote: [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ wordparty ---        
remote: [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!        
remote: [INFO] Compiling 11 source files to /var/lib/openshift/549f36af5973caa3de00018f/app-root/runtime/repo/target/classes        
remote: [INFO]         
remote: [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ wordparty ---               
remote: [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.        
remote: [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/lib/openshift/549f36af5973caa3de00018f/app-root/runtime/repo/src/test/resources        
remote: [INFO]         
remote: [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ wordparty ---        
remote: [INFO] No sources to compile        
remote: [INFO]         
remote: [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ wordparty ---        
remote: [INFO] Tests are skipped.        
remote: [INFO]         
remote: [INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.4:war (default-war) @ wordparty ---        
remote: [INFO] Packaging webapp        
remote: [INFO] Assembling webapp [wordparty] in [/var/lib/openshift/549f36af5973caa3de00018f/app-root/runtime/repo/target/wordparty-1.0-SNAPSHOT]        
remote: [INFO] Processing war project        
remote: [INFO] Copying webapp resources [/var/lib/openshift/549f36af5973caa3de00018f/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/webapp]        
remote: [INFO] Webapp assembled in [378 msecs]        
remote: [INFO] Building war: /var/lib/openshift/549f36af5973caa3de00018f/app-root/runtime/repo/target/ROOT.war        
remote: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------        
remote: [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS        
remote: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------        
remote: [INFO] Total time: 10.679s        
remote: [INFO] Finished at: Fri Jan 02 11:09:33 EST 2015        
remote: [INFO] Final Memory: 14M/113M        
remote: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------        
remote: [WARNING] The requested profile "openshift" could not be activated because it does not exist.        
remote: Preparing build for deployment        
remote: Deployment id is 0b02f11c        
remote: Activating deployment        
remote: Starting MongoDB cartridge        
remote: Waiting for mongo to start...        
remote: Starting jbossews cartridge        
remote: Found 127.8.119.129:8080 listening port        
remote: -------------------------        
remote: Git Post-Receive Result: success        
remote: Activation status: success        
remote: Deployment completed with status: success
```

Here is the remote tomcat log:

```
==> app-root/logs/jbossews.log <==
Jan 02, 2015 11:09:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina addClusterRuleSet
INFO: Cluster RuleSet not found due to [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.ha.ClusterRuleSet]. Cluster configuration disabled.
Jan 02, 2015 11:09:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina addClusterRuleSet
INFO: Cluster RuleSet not found due to [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.ha.ClusterRuleSet]. Cluster configuration disabled.
Jan 02, 2015 11:09:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /opt/rh/v8314/root/usr/lib64:/opt/rh/mongodb24/root/usr/lib64:/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib
Jan 02, 2015 11:09:46 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-127.8.119.129-8080"]
Jan 02, 2015 11:09:46 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1846 ms
Jan 02, 2015 11:09:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jan 02, 2015 11:09:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.54
Jan 02, 2015 11:09:46 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/openshift/549f36af5973caa3de00018f/app-root/runtime/dependencies/jbossews/webapps/ROOT.war
Jan 02, 2015 11:09:50 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive /var/lib/openshift/549f36af5973caa3de00018f/app-root/runtime/dependencies/jbossews/webapps/ROOT.war has finished in 3,922 ms
Jan 02, 2015 11:09:50 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-127.8.119.129-8080"]
Jan 02, 2015 11:09:50 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 4055 ms
```

P.S. I am trying to deploy at the root.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was in pom.xml. I merged files from my bitbucket repo with my openshift repo and consequence of this action is that I have deleted profile with "openshift" id. After adding the default one all works perfectly.

```
 <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>openshift</id>
        <build>
            <finalName>{APP_NAME}</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>webapps</outputDirectory>
                        <warName>ROOT</warName>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

Comment: I'm also having that issue when I created an App using [this repo](https://github.com/arshadalisoomro/java-blog) Please have a look at [this OS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30954158/how-to-deploy-spring-mvc-project-on-openshift) and suggest me a solution as well! please.

Comment: worked also for me, but for JBoss app according to [this](https://developers.openshift.com/en/jbosseap-repository-layout.html)  `outputDirectory` has to be set to `deployments`

Comment: here is the link to guide where Template Repository Layout is described:
https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/blob/master/documentation/oo_cartridge_guide.adoc#tomcat