# how to deploy Spring MVC project on openshift.com

Tags: java, spring-mvc, openshift

I wanted to Deploy a simple Spring MVC APP to open shift I googled for this and found [spring-mvc-3-on-jboss](https://blog.openshift.com/spring-mvc-3-on-jboss/) but there project structure is different  I have basic Spring MVC project structure is 
[image]
 that is at [this repo](https://github.com/arshadalisoomro/java-blog), at openshift.com I created Application and configured as :
But I can not see my *home.jsp* file as welcome file when I goto my app-url I see only the default/traditional welcome page.
 Any suggestion how to configure project to work correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one major problem with your pom.xml, I think that makes your app not working on the openshift.com. You should add the following lines to your pom.xml

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <!-- When built in OpenShift the 'openshift' profile will be used when 
            invoking mvn. -->
        <!-- Use this profile for any OpenShift specific customization your app 
            will need. -->
        <!-- By default that is to put the resulting archive into the 'webapps' 
            folder. -->
        <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html -->
        <id>openshift</id>
        <build>
            <finalName>yourAppName</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>webapps</outputDirectory>
                        <warName>ROOT</warName>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

I haven't tested this code with `JBoss Application Server`, so change your server to `Apache Tomcat 7`. that worked for me correctly.

Comment: I have tired in this way, but I still am unable to get my app working correctly. Please will you do this for me I will add you as __contributor__ to my project. Add me on [g+](https://plus.google.com/+ArshadAliSoomro) we will do futher steps there.

Answer (score 2):

first you have clone your git repository then automatically created folder in document folder.

then your war file extract and past your clone directory into webapps folder

and create test folder paste your code in folder and also root war file.

then your ulr in your folder name write and enter.

for example

like this.

```
git clone ssh://5565c850e0b8cd07580001ba@yourdomain.rhcloud.com
```

paste your extract war file into your clone directory.

then fire git commmand

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "A checkin to my application"
$ git push
```

Comment: I have pushed that repo from github how to get that work?

Comment: you have push repo then deployement is successfull your application message in terminal.then open in browser.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get what you want to say, but I don't have any copy of  repo at my local machine, I have pushed that  from github.com!

Comment: you have give souce code of github,but openshift into no need to give github source. they have already inbuilt git in openshift.

Comment: See my Edit and think about it! what to do with this one??